# EntityType Has No Key Defined Using String as Key

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I am getting the 'EntityType Has No Key Defined' error in an asp.net mvc 6 app.  All research points towards definging the 'key' attribute in the model,  however I have correctly done this here and the problem still exists:

```
public class InvoiceCategory
{

    [Key]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The above shows the complete entity, there is no other columns, the name column is the primary key.

Additional info:  I am trying to implement a select list as follows:

```
ViewBag.Category = new SelectList(
await DbContext.InvoiceCategory.ToListAsync(),
"Name","Name", (object)invoiceItem.Category);
```

Any ideas why I am getting the above error in this situation?

Comment: Can't explain this, but neither can I recommend this. Having meaningful primary keys is not sensible. You're never going to change a name any more.

Comment: @Gert this is a simple lookup list.  It is not relational and a primary key is not even necessary however I set it to try and solve the problem, the only constraint is the list is unique.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you try to use int as KEY not string.

Comment: I cant use integer because the name column is a string.  It is the only column and I don't want to add an int id column just for a simple lookup list.

Comment: well the key is id for that reason I think you need to use int just try and you will see if is that the problem :)

Comment: If I add an integer column to the database so I have "id, name" then yes it will work but that means I have to add a pointless column to my database which I don't want to do.   I just want a simple lookup list of type string.  Am I missing something?

Comment: ok :) EF framework prompt 'no key' is that EF framework needs a primary key in database. To declaratively tell EF which property the key is, you add a [Key] annotation. Or, the quickest way, add an ID property. Then, the EF framework will take ID as the primary key by default. Have a nice day:)

Comment: Yes that's how I understand it as well, but I don't understand why it does not work when I define my 'name' column as the key.  Does it absolutely have to have an integer as the primary key?

Comment: I don't literally care I want to help. If I can I don't have enough rating to write just comment because of that I just write answer :) have a good day.

Comment: well that maybe help // Option 3  use the Key attribute.

        //[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key]

        public string Name { get; set; }


http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2012/01/25/some-gotchas-when-using-asp-net-mvc-with-entity-framework-code-first.aspx

Comment: "I don't have enough rating to write just comment because of that I just write answer " I voted this down exactly for that reason. Raising the bar for comments has a reason. Evading that by writing answers makes it worse. It's not helpful at all. In this specific case: the OP wants a string as key. Changing it to int is clearly not an option.

Comment: @Nikolay As you can see from my original post, I am already defining the 'Key' attribute however it does not work.